# Generate registration token for FCM using Cordova

Tags: android, cordova, cordova-plugins

Using the FCM plugin - Cordova project, trying to generate the registration token.

```
FCMPlugin.getToken(function(token) {
                console.log('reg token: ' + token);
                alert(token);
            }, function(err) {
                console.log('error retrieving token: ' + err);
            })
```

I need one clarity , how to pass the Sender Id as a parameter on the above request ?

Answer (score 0):

Google have created Firebase for push notification. Google strongly advises to use the FCM instead of old GCM.

In the current FCM cordova push notification plugin you don't need the "SENDER ID".

You have to register your app in http://www.console.firebase.google.com

Then after providing your app name and few details about your app, google will provide you with two files.

1) google-services.json
2) GoogleService-Info.plist

If you are developing android app then you need to keep the .json file in the android root directory.

OR If you are developing IOS app then you need to keep the .plist file in the android root directory.

Then in the index.js file in the **onDeviceReady** function use this code

```
FCMPlugin.getToken(
      function(token){
        //alert(token);
        $.post("http://example.com/api/addToken",{tok:token},function(data){
            if(data)
            {
                // DO some function here if the token is added to the database
            }                
        });
      },
      function(err){
        console.log('error retrieving token: ' + err);
        alert('error retrieving token: ' + err);
      }
    )
```

That's all. Check whether this works for you or not at least works for me.. :)